# Flask-SocketIO cannot emit event using emit() function directly

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to connect my React App and Flask App using SocketIO and I am facing an issue that I can't understand. The App is simple as it changes the background color of the page in both the tabs if you click on the color button in one using sockets. My Simple code for React and Flask is as follows:

**Structure**

```
frontend/src/App.js 
backend/__init__.py
backend/socket_listeners.py
manage.py
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {

   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        color: ''
      };

      this.socket = io(`http://${document.domain}:5000`);

      this.socket.on('receive_change_color', (color) => {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      });

   }

   send = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("emitting", this.state.color);
     this.socket.emit('send_change_color', this.state.color);
   }

   setColor = (color) => {
     this.setState({color: color});
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      axios.get("http://localhost:5000/sample")
       .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
   }

  render() {

      return (
         <div style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>
            <button onClick={(e) => this.send(e)}>Change color</button>
            <button id="blue" onClick={()=>this.setColor('blue')}>Blue</button>
            <button id="red" onClick={() => this.setColor('red')}>Red</button>
         </div>
      );
    }
 }

export default App;
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from backend.controllers.api import api
from backend import assets
from backend.models import db

from backend.extensions import (
    cache,
    debug_toolbar,
    login_manager,
    migrate,
)

def create_app(object_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(object_name)
    CORS(app, resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
    cache.init_app(app)
    debug_toolbar.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    return app
```

**socket_listeners.py**

```
import os
from backend import create_app
from flask_socketio import  SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, emit

env = os.environ.get('BACKEND_ENV', 'dev')
app = create_app('backend.settings.%sConfig' % env.capitalize())

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
   emit('connect', {'data': "sample"})

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
   print("Disconnected to socket!")

@socketio.on('send_change_color')
def change_color(color):
    print("Color: ", color)
    emit('receive_change_color', color) **this doesnt work**
    # socketio.emit('receive_change_color', color) **this works**
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from flask import current_app
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from flask_script.commands import ShowUrls, Clean
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand
from backend.socket_listeners import socketio, app
from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room, emit
from backend import create_app
from backend.models import db, User

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("server", Server(threaded=True))
manager.add_command("show-urls", ShowUrls())
manager.add_command("clean", Clean())
manager.add_command("db", MigrateCommand)

@manager.shell
def make_shell_context():
   return dict(app=app, db=db, User=User)

@manager.command
def createdb():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

@manager.command
def runsocket():
    socketio.run(
       app,
       host="0.0.0.0"
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

As shown in the **socket_listeners.py** the last line in **change_color** function socketio.emit() works but the line above it doesn't. As per the documentation emit() method should work directly but I am not able to change the color on the UI 
or emit the recieve_change_color using the emit() method directly.

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: The difference between `emit()` and `socketio.emit()` is that the former only goes to the client that originated the event currently being handled, while the latter broadcasts to all clients. Any chance you have more than one client in this application and expect this event to go to the wrong one? You may want to enable logging in the server and the client to see what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I have more than one client so the event might go to the wrong client as you said. The end goal here is to create a google doc type of application. So, I guess I should use socketio.emit() rather than emit().