# Using emit in route Flask python

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am having trouble using emit in my route, I have tried many things but nothing seems to be working. My code is as follows:

**app.py**:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/abc')
def index():
    emit('message', {'data': 'Demo'})
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

**index.html**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log("Connected")
        });
        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log(msg.data);
        });
        
</script>
```

(?) How can I use `emit` in `route`?

Comment: Read Miguel's comment left in the this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129280/flask-socketio-cannot-emit-event-using-emit-function-directly)

Answer (score 0):

Your design is flawed, since you are emitting too early.

Here is the sequence of events:

- Client connects to the `/abc` route from the browser
- The `index()` route runs and calls `emit()`. At this point the client is not connected, so it does not receive the message.
- The `index()` function returns the `index.html` template to the browser.
- The browser renders the HTML page, and as part of that executes the JavaScript code in it, which makes a Socket.IO connection to the server.

What you can do to verify that the emit is working is open this route in multiple browser tabs. When you open the first one nothing will happen, but when you open the second tab, the client on the first tab is going to receive the emit, since it is already connected. When you open the third tab, tabs 1 and 2 will receive the emit.

Comment: Yes, I just tried again and it is correct as you said. However, I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing to fix, the application is doing what you told it to do. If you want the emit to happen later, then you need to use a design that can do this. There is actually no point to emitting something in the route, the emit should happen as a result of some external event, I suppose.